# What is the most appropriate word for the reverse of ableism?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

This is a writing question for a realistic sci-fi book I'm working on. *Ableism* means discrimination against people who are disabled. What would be the best word, made up (or not made up) for discriminating against people with enhanced abilities? *Superableism? Reverse ableism?* Is there a better term that isn't used much?

Comment: Ableism means "discrimination based on ability". So technically it could be used to both describe discrimination of people with limited abilities as well as discrimination of people with extraordinary abilities. But practically I wouldn't consider it appropriate to use the same term, because disabled and superpowered people are completely different minorities who get discriminated for completely different reasons.

Comment: I see.  What about disableism?  I guess that sounds bad, but enhanced people could say that normal people are disabled by comparison and they're being favored by the law.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you talking about *discriminating against* people who have extraordinary abilities, or *celebrating* them?

Comment: Discriminating against people with abilities.

Comment: "Reverse racism" is when people who are commonly discriminated because of their race begin to discriminate those who are not of their race. "Reverse ableism" would therefore be when people who are discriminated because of their disability begin to discriminate people without that disability. It wouldn't designate discrimination by average people against above-average abilities.

Comment: I think this would be better suited to the English site. Sending it there.

Comment: Have you considered "zetaism"?

Comment: Please remember that asking for / encouraging D-I-Y suggestions (ie strings not in the lexicon, or words actually in the lexicon but only having other meanings) is off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Enhanceism* just doesn't roll off the tongue, does it? (Not my unenhanced tongue, anyway.)

Consider *augmentism.*

Comment: While I like the word, there's nothing about it out of context which expresses a negative bias against the augmented.

Comment: The -ism, like in ableism,  has become associated with stuff similar to fascism.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to come up with a term for your enhanced people first (inhumans, specials, supers, amazings, whatever). Then you can either slap an *anti-* in the front of that or coin a new slang term — someone anti-inhuman could be *pure human*, for example. Anti-amazing could be *unzing* (which you could then extrapolate into "people who are good without powers" are "unzung heroes," that kind of thing).